# How do I detect if an installation of Code-Composer-Studio is licensed?

Tags: texas-instruments, code-composer

The licensed version of the CCSv4 can be used to create programs with more then 16kByte code.

When I have a PC with Eclipse/CCS installed, how do I detect, if the current version is licensed without writing source code for more than 16kByte code size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The license file is located at

```
 C:\Program Files\Texas Instruments\ccsv4\DebugServer\license.lic
```

You can read which license is available.

See also:

`C:\Program Files\Texas Instruments\ccsv4\DebugServer\licenselocation.txt`